# Python print Xpath element gives empty array

Tags: python, xpath

I'm trying to get the xpath of an element in site https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/BTCUSD/technicals/
Specifically the result under the summary speedometer. Whether it's buy or sell.

[Speedometer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQVhw.png)

Using Google Chrome xpath I get the result

```
//*[@id="technicals-root"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/span[2]
```

and to try and get that data in python I plugged it into

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/BTCUSD/technicals/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
status = tree.xpath('//*[@id="technicals-root"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/span[2]/text()')
```

When I print status I get an empty array. But it doesn't seem like anything is wrong with the xpath. I've read that google does some shenanigans with incorrectly written HTML tables which will output the wrong xpath but that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: `<div id="technicals-root" style="min-height:600px;"></div>` is empty, is that what you are asking?

Comment: When I use Chrome's inspect to examine that element I see that it's within a span. I can't find the span within the downloaded html which suggests that it's built using Javascript within the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run your code, the "technicals-root" div is empty. I assume javascript is filling it in. When you can't get a page statically, you can always turn to [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to run a browser and let it figure everything out. You may have to tweak the driver path to get it working in your environment but this works for me:

```
import time
import contextlib
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument(" — incognito")

with contextlib.closing(webdriver.Chrome(
        executable_path='/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver', 
        chrome_options=option)) as browser:

    browser.get('https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/BTCUSD/technicals/')

    # wait until js has filled in the element - and a bit longer for js churn
    WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, 
        '//*[@id="technicals-root"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/span')))
    time.sleep(1)

    status = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="technicals-root"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/span[2]')
    print(status[0].text)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking! Thanks a lot!